# Font is loading as Bold and not Un-Bolding

Tags: html, css

---

My font is auto loading as bold and won't behave to the 'normal' property. I want it to be standard and then bold it when i need it. In addition, it is not changing to normal at any other part of the document.

Can someone help me?

```
@font-face {
font-family: Avenir;
src: url('type/AvenirNext.ttc');
font-weight: normal;
```

Comment: 1. look in `Avenir` docs if it's defined as bold font... 2.take a look in F12 (dev tool) maybe `font-weight: normal;` override by something else

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get your font file? Are you sure that it can be used for multiple weights? From [this git repository](https://github.com/potyt/fonts/tree/master/macfonts/Avenir%20Next) it seems like there are different files for different weights.

If you think you can use your file for multiple weights, you could try using a range of weights like `font-weight: 400 700;` as described in [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).

Those docs also recommend specifying a font format `src: url('type/AvenirNext.ttc') format("truetype");`.

If none of this works, are you able to post a link demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score -1):

```css
.fonts {
  font-family: Avenir;
  src: url('type/AvenirNext.ttc');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fonts">This is text</div>
```

Whatever you have to take a class name that is conflicting to properties, Now you have to see the above code I have to change the class name it's working.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
@font-face {
font-family: Avenir;
src: url('type/AvenirNext.ttc');
font-weight: unset!important;
```